# Hex editor with binary templates

Tags: templates, binary, hex, editor

I have to handle binary data files. As a researcher I may define new formats for raw data and need to implement other less known and even lesser documented binary formats.

For that I looking for a hex editor with some features to capture the knowledge already explored from various cryptic sources, like prototype implementation and scientific papers.

I really like the binary templates implemented in 010 editor https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/templates.html . I think this is one feature which could solve my predicament. But I would like to evaluate all of my other options before I choose my tool.

So any suggestions are welcomed! I mainly use Windows but not afraid of Linux (Ubuntu to be more precise). However I do not have access to iOS.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off topic on SO.

Comment: I appreciate the to the point comment. I just have a clarification question. Is there a difference between "which tool is the best?" and "which tool supports this and that features, since I have to do this?" type questions? My intuition was that the first one is problematic since it is subjective, but the second one is an objective question about a crucial aspect of the profession. Sorry if I ask an inappropriate question. Do you know any forums where I could gather more information about the topic?